# this is referring to the class which it is part of and not the one from which the instance is called

Tags: javascript, oop, this

```
class ElPush {
  pushElement(type) {
    document
      .querySelector(`#${type}-projects`)
      .querySelectorAll("li")
      .forEach((el) => {
        this.itemLog.push(el);
      });
  }
}
```

i want to use class ElPush to push element to itemLog array which is present in class ActiveItem given below

```
class ActiveItem {
  constructor() {
    this.itemLog = [];
    const elPush = new ElPush();
    elPush.pushElement("active");

    console.log(this.itemLog);
  }
}
class FinishedItem {
  constructor() {
    this.itemLog = [];
    const elPush = new ElPush();
    elPush.pushElement("finished");

    console.log(this.itemLog);
  }
}
class App {
  static init() {
    const activeList = new ActiveItem();
  }
}
App.init();
```

this `this.itemLog.push(el);` line in ElPush is throwing error `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

I know this is not a practical solution,but I am just practising opp concepts ,and would really like any solution offered

Comment: As you use a method of `ActiveItem` inside `ElPush.pushElement`, you either have to pass `ActiveItem` instance there or add respective container property to `ElPush`

Comment: I don't understand; itemLog isn't a property of ElPush; why would you expect this to work?

Comment: If the OP wants to keep the class based approach, then `itemLog` should be a property of any `ElPush` instance, but not of an `ActiveItem` instance. The logging within the latter, as shown with the example code, then should be `console.log(elPush.itemLog)`. Any approach that keeps `itemLog` a property of  any `ActiveItem` instance has to provide `push` functionality by other, not class based, (composition) techniques.

Comment: Actually there are multiple classes where ElPush is needed so the itemLog of each class should be different ,all I want is to use same ElPush class to push different element in different item Log based on the Type parameter of pushElement.

Comment: @abhinaykhalatkar ... *"... all I want is to use same ElPush class to push different element in different item Log based on the Type parameter of pushElement."* ... But one does not need at all a class abstraction for this task. A simple helper/utility function already does the job sufficient enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// - still class based for being recognizable to the OP.
// - the query part should be refactored
//   as simple helper/utility function.
//
class ProjectItemQuery {
  query(type) {
    return Array.from(document
      .querySelector(`#${ type }-projects`)
      .querySelectorAll("li")
    );
  }
}

// refactored query helper.
function queryProjectItems(type) {
  return Array.from(document
    .querySelector(`#${ type }-projects`)
    .querySelectorAll("li")
  );
}

class ActiveItems {
  constructor() {
    const itemQuery = new ProjectItemQuery;

    this.list = itemQuery.query("active");
  //this.list = queryProjectItems("active");

    console.log('ActiveItems :: list : ', this.list);
  }
}

class FinishedItems {
  constructor() {
    this.list = queryProjectItems("finished");

    console.log('FinishedItems :: list : ', this.list);
  }
}

class App {
  static init() {
    const activeItemList = (new ActiveItems).list;
    const finishedItemList = (new FinishedItems).list;

    console.log('App :: init :: activeItemList : ', activeItemList);
    console.log('App :: init :: finishedItemList : ', finishedItemList);
  }
}
App.init();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<ul id='active-projects'>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
</ul>

<ul id='finished-projects'>
  <li>baz</li>
  <li>biz</li>
</ul>
```

#### Edit

***Q***

- abhinay khalatkar

> i went with this return approach already but what I wanted to know is, if the above-given way will work or not?i mean is it possible to change the property of class (a) from a different class(b) using "bind()" and "this" if class (b) is instantiated in this class(a) ? I don't want a workaround but a straightforward way to do this.if not I will go with this way. Thank you for the A2A.

***A***

- Peter Seliger

> Of course one can .. there are even many ways of achieving this task. But why does one want to add more complexity (here ... less good to read, easier to screw up with thus more error prone) to one's design instead of keeping it clean and lightweight?

Compare the above given example code to the one that is going to provided next. What happens with the former is much more readable / clear / comprehensible than what is coming now ...

```js
// - a less favourable, function based, mixin approach
//
function ProjectItemQueryMixin() {
  if (!Array.isArray(this.list)) {
    this.list = [];
  } 
  this.queryAndPush = function (type) {
    document
      .querySelector(`#${ type }-projects`)
      .querySelectorAll("li")
      .forEach(elm => this.list.push(elm));
  }
}

class ActiveItems {
  constructor() {
    // this.list = [];

    // - Applying the mixin based `query` 
    //   method directly to an instance
    //   is the less favourable way.
    ProjectItemQueryMixin.call(this);

    this.queryAndPush("active");

    console.log('ActiveItems :: list : ', this.list);
  }
}

class FinishedItems {
  constructor() {
    // this.list = [];

    this.queryAndPush("finished");

    console.log('FinishedItems :: list : ', this.list);
  }
}
ProjectItemQueryMixin.call(FinishedItems.prototype);
// - Applying the mixin based `query` method to the
//   prototype was the choice for everyone that is
//   concerned about design and memory usage.
// - A lot of developers will find this confusing as well.

class App {
  static init() {
    const activeItemList = (new ActiveItems).list;
    const finishedItemList = (new FinishedItems).list;

    console.log('App :: init :: activeItemList : ', activeItemList);
    console.log('App :: init :: finishedItemList : ', finishedItemList);
  }
}
App.init();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<ul id='active-projects'>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
</ul>

<ul id='finished-projects'>
  <li>baz</li>
  <li>biz</li>
</ul>
```

***3rd Iteration**, this time as close as possible to the OP's code*

```js
// ... Again, one does not need a class instance for this task.
//
// A simple function/method with `this` context called
// `queryAndPushProjectItems(type)` would already solve
// the OP's problem.
//
class ProjectItemQuery {
  queryAndPush(type) {
    document
      .querySelector(`#${ type }-projects`)
      .querySelectorAll("li")
      .forEach(elm => this.list.push(elm));
  }
}

class ProjectItems {
  // - The constructor's `type` argument prevents
  //   copying over and over the same item class
  //   related code that just differs in how items
  //   are going to be queried.
  constructor(type) {
    this.list = [];

    const itemQuery = new ProjectItemQuery;

    // - This code block answers th OP's question.
    // - Call `queryAndPush` of the above created
    //   `ProjectItemQuery` instance within the
    //   `this` context of any `ProjectItems`
    //   instance.
    // - Of course this is not a desirable design.
    itemQuery.queryAndPush.call(this, type);
    // - or ...
    // `queryAndPushProjectItems.call(this, type);`

    console.log('ProjectItems :: type, list : ', type, this.list);
  }
}

class App {
  static init() {
    const activeItems = new ProjectItems('active');
    const finishedItems = new ProjectItems('finished');

    console.log('App :: init :: activeItems.list : ', activeItems.list);
    console.log('App :: init :: finishedItems.list : ', finishedItems.list);
  }
}
App.init();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<ul id='active-projects'>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
</ul>

<ul id='finished-projects'>
  <li>baz</li>
  <li>biz</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i went with this return approach already but what I wanted to know is, if the above-given way will work or not?i mean is it possible to change the property of class (a)  from a different class(b) using "bind()" and "this" if class (b) is instantiated in this class(a)  ? I don't want a workaround but a straightforward way to do this.if not I will go with this way. Thank you for the A2A.

Comment: Of course one can .. there are even many ways of achieving this task. But why does one want to add more complexity (here ... less good to read, easier to screw up with thus more error prone) to ones design instead of keeping it clean and lightweight?

Comment: thanks for the quick response. yeah,i get your point,direct way will just make it harder to track my original list items if more methods are responsible for changing the list,but just for practice sake,how can I achieve this? i mean directly changing elements itemLog using ElPush(not with returning back the value from the instance but directly from ElPush class).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62759519/13877764 <= this way still have list in just one class which is responsible for separating elements from DOM,what I wanna do is define a list for finishItems and ActiveItems (mean two different list in there respective class). and the class responsible for seprating it will only push item in list of the class which is calling that instance of class.(if its an active el then will go to activeItem list and if finished el then it will go to the list of finished item

Comment: I don't quite understand ... every given approach of mine does exactly what you're asking for ... *"... what I wanna do is define a list for finishItems and ActiveItems (mean two different list in there respective class)."* ... was it _**( ... two different lists, each in their particular/respective class).**_ And just as a remark, there is not even a need for two class implementations that just differ in the query.

Comment: its not about the result,but the way the result is given,your solution is arguably the most efficient way of doing this and its really easy to understand.and I know the way i am saying is more complicated and will just result in an overcomplicated code,but still can u provide a solution for the first given code snippet? i mean two distinct lists made from a single class there respective class.again sorry if this doesn't make much sense ,I don't know what I am asking for properly,I just started learning js about a week ago, any further clarification from your side will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It just got provided to you with the ... _"**3rd Iteration**, this time as close as possible to the OP's code"_ ... of the above answer. You might then consider it to be the accepted answer, I'm done for today.

Comment: yup, that's perfect man, thanks a lot for such great query solving. again sorry for my bad explaining.but you solved it perfectly man, thanks, great first experience on StackOverflow. just one last thing, what do you mean by OP? i first thought its operation process ,but I see from your last snippet it must not be that.

Comment: OP means *Original Poster* (or *Original Post*)